# GIO: How to enable a GMenuItem? GMenu enable / disable

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gio

### Problem

I create a `GMenuModel` and set is as application app menu.
However, the items in the app are disabled.

**Q:** How do I enable them?

### Code

```
GMenuModel * createMenu(){

  GMenu * menu = g_menu_new();

  g_menu_append(menu, "Item1", "item1_action1");    
  return (GMenuModel*)menu;
}

...

GMenuModel * menu = createMenu(GTK_APPLICATION(app));
  
gtk_application_set_app_menu(GTK_APPLICATION(app), (GMenuModel*)menu);

g_object_unref (menu);


GActionEntry actions[] = {
  {"item1_action1", exampleAction, NULL, NULL, NULL}
};
g_action_map_add_action_entries(G_ACTION_MAP(app),actions, 1, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem**: The menu items are not connected to existing actions.

**Your solution**: Set the correct `detailed_action` when creating the menu item. (it is missing the prefix `app.`).

### Code

```
GMenuModel * createMenu(){      
  GMenu * menu = g_menu_new();

  g_menu_append(menu, "Item1", "app.item1_action1");    
  return (GMenuModel*)menu;
}
```

### How to figure this out?

- Run your app with the inspector: `GTK_DEBUG=interactive ./a.out`
- Double click any item to open its properties.
- Choose `Actions` from the combo box. That is, the ones you register with `g_action_map_add_action_entries`**!**
- See the column `Prefix` showing `app`.
- `g_action_map_add_action_entries(G_ACTION_MAP(app),...)` registers actions for the app. Therefore it adds an `app` prefix to the action names.
- So in your menu creation you need to use the full name (ie `app.item1_action1`) as `detailed_action` name.
- Be aware of the Prefix column, that says `app`